# How to determine if a table has been accessed in the last month?

Tags: oracle, performance

In Oracle 10, is it possible to determine when the last time a table was accessed?

According to [this article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_monitoring_table_usage.htm) the data is there, but I'm not sure whether this is reset whenever the server is restarted, nor how to actually get the access information.

We're actually trying to determine what tables are no longer used.

Comment: Sorry Chris, I missed the "accessed" part of your question and thus the answer I provided was incorrect.  It would only show you the last time a DML statement was executed on the the table.  I have deleted my answer.

Comment: I also answered with a reference to dba_tab_modifications, overlooking SELECT's.  I think you'll have to set up auditing on the tables to get this info.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to determine table modifications is to check [DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4149.htm#sthref1900), their values remain throught shutdown. You have to do a comparision between two intervals of time.

**UPDATE**: About the article. It refers to [DBA_HIST_SEG_xxx](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/toc.htm) tables which gets data from [V$segsta](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2076.htm#i1414197)t. The data in this system view is reset on startup.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at this asktom question http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2975793633621 ?

It takes a while to get going but if you search for "simple way last date of table used" it may be of some use.

Hope it helps

Cheers

Ian

Comment: The summary is: enable table audit. But you have to do it and wait auditing to retrieve info. I find @FerranB's answer a better solution.